# Convergence of $\frac{1}{n( \sqrt{n^2+n}-n)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Investigate convergence of the series: $$\frac{1}{n( \sqrt{n^2+n}-n)}$$
Which criterion should be used?

Comment: As a sequence or a series?

Comment: series, my mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or rewrite:

$$\frac{1}{n\left( \sqrt{n^2+n}-n \right)} = \frac{\sqrt{n^2+n}+n}{n\left( \sqrt{n^2+n}-n \right)\left( \sqrt{n^2+n}+n \right)} = \frac{\sqrt{n^2+n}+n}{n^2}  $$

And then:

$$\frac{\sqrt{n^2+n}+n}{n^2} \ge \frac{\sqrt{n^2}+n}{n^2} = \frac{2n}{n^2} = \frac{2}{n} $$

So since $\sum \tfrac{2}{n}$ diverges...

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** You may write, as $n \to +\infty$:
$$
\frac{1}{n( \sqrt{n^2+n}-n)}=\frac{1}{n^2( \sqrt{1+\frac1n}-1)}=\frac{1}{n^2\left(\frac{1}{2n}+\mathcal{O}\left({\frac1{n^2}}\right)\right)}\sim \frac2n
$$ and the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n( \sqrt{n^2+n}-n)}$ is **divergent**.

Comment: It seems only French users systematically resort to $\sim$ asymptotical evaluations to prove convergence/divergence of series. Most people are limited to comparison test, which is too bad.

Answer (score 1):

Right answer is: 
$$ \frac{1}{n \cdot (\sqrt{n^2+n} - n) } = \frac{(\sqrt{n^2+n} + n)}{n \cdot (\sqrt{n^2+n} - n) \cdot (\sqrt{n^2+n} + n) } = \frac{n \cdot (\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}} + 1)}{n \cdot (n ^2 + n - n^2)} = \frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}} + 1}{n } $$ 
And then you can do with this whatever you want.
This is quite common technic for such problems.